# Xcode NSUserDefaults turn NULL/nil after a few screens

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Have an app - Xcode 11, iOS 13 - that has (so far) 8 screens. On the first screen the user keys in his/her last and first names and I use the following to store (and it works)

```
NSString *value1 = _lastName.text;
NSString *value2 = _firstName.text;
NSLog(@"Firstname: %@", value1);
NSLog(@"Lastname: %@", value2);
NSUserDefaults *saved = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: value1 forKey:@"curLast"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: value2 forKey:@"curFirst"];
[saved synchronize];
```

One the 2nd screen another string is saved (and it works)

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: newvalue forKey:@"curData"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

I use curData on the next 3 screens - works. On the 5th screen I use the curLast and curFirst - works. But on the next screen I try to retrieve the curLast and curFirst again:

```
NSString *lsaved = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"curLast"];
    NSString *lsaved2 = [lsaved stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSString *fsaved = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"curFirst"];

    NSLog (@"Last%@ First %@", lsaved2, fsaved);
```

They are both (null).

I've seen other SO threads about this but on earlier versions and allegedly there was a fix. Are suggestions?

Comment: I've never seen `NSUserDefaults` misbehave in this way. Are you sure nothing is removing those keys? Unrelated: "synchronize is deprecated and will be marked with the API_DEPRECATED macro in a future release." - remove those calls.

Comment: I had to look up how to remove a key - never did it. Google Xcode  nsuserdefault value null - you will find a lot of hits in SO and the net.  But you got me thinking: wondering if I have a corrupt .m file for one view controller - loses the value there every time now. And the NSLog entries to print out the values are still outputting after I took them out. Already clean, clean folder, and rebooted many times - going to try to delete Derived Data - if that doesn't work I will have to recreate the .m   PS - thanks for the heads up on synchronize - so it's automatic in 14?

Comment: Resolved: entire View Controller must have been corrupt - had to delete the segue's, delete the VC, delete the .h and .m, create new .h and .m and rewire.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) - synchronize has been marked as almost deprecated for quite some time already, I believe that change was made in iOS 8.